# Is there a way to disable OS X's firewall for a specific executable?

Tags: macos, firewall

I'm a developer and I'm coding a C++ web server, and as part of the development iteration process I have to compile a new executable which opens listening sockets.

This triggers the GUI prompt to allow connections through the firewall to this newly compiled executable.

I'd temporarily disable the system's firewall but I know it will just lead to me having the firewall disabled for the next several months until I stumble back onto that system settings page (like last time...).

But I will go nuts if I have to click the dialog box every damn time I test.

Maybe there is some way I can convince the OS to not prompt me for executables found in a specific directory? Or a terminal command I can run (no matter how elaborate) to add an exemption for the newly compiled executable to the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a lot of time to test this out, but this seems to be working.

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --unblockapp $APP_PATH
```